# Differences between @Interceptors and @InterceptorBinding + @Logged?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations, cdi, interceptor

Seems there are two ways to binding interceptor to target class/method:

1. [@Interceptors on target class/method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkedm.html)
2. [Declare a `interceptor binding type`(aka, a custom annotation annotated with @InterceptorBinding itself, for example @Logged), and using it on target class/method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkhjx.html)

I am using interceptor in CDI environment. My question is, does it is completely unnecessary to declare a extra `interceptor binding type` if I using @Interceptors to binding interceptor to my target methods?

If answer is **yes**, then why IntelliJ IDEA constantly complaint me a error

> @Interceptor must specify at least one interceptor binding

when I am not annotating `interceptor binding type` on my interceptor?

If answer is **no**, I already binding my interceptor to target class/method with @Interceptors(arrayOfMyInceptor) **directly**, why declare a extra `interceptor binding type` and using it on my interceptor?

I search the web but cannt found anything about difference of this two approaches, hope SO can solve my problem.

Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annotations `@Interceptor` and other costum annotations like `@Logged` are supposed to be invoked on a interceptor class, e.g.

```
@Logged
@Interceptor
@Priority(Interceptor.Priority.APPLICATION)
public class LoggedInterceptor implements Serializable { ... }
```

The annotation `@InterceptorBinding` has to be invoked on the annotation you want to create to make clear it's somewhat of a "interceptor qualifier".

```
@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
public @interface Logged {
}
```

Then you can invoke the interceptor-binding annotation on a (managed) bean or its methods.

```
@Logged
public String pay() {...}

@Logged
public void reset() {...}
```

> See the java tutorial for more help https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-adv006.htm

**EDIT**

Because I misread your question, here's my edit:
The annotation `@Interceptors` is like a collection of interceptors.
By passing several interceptor classes (e.g. `LoggedInterceptor` from `@Logged`) to the `value` variable of the applied `@Interceptors` annotation all those inteceptor bindings are invoked:

```
@Interceptors({LoggedInterceptor.class,
OtherInterceptor.class,.....})
```

Thus you need at least one interceptor binding  for `@Interceptors`

**So you need an interceptor binding for the interceptor class itself *but not* for the target class since it's already mentioned in the @Interceptors annotation.**

> See the API documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/interceptor/Interceptors.html

Comment: Thanks for answer. but that's not what I asked. What I asked is differences between apply @Interceptors and @Logged on target class/method, and if `interceptor binding type`(@Logged here) is **optional** when using @Interceptors on target class/method?

Comment: See the updated answer. And no, you don't need to apply an interceptor binding type since it's already included in @Interceptors(...)

Comment: Sorry for misleading, updated again. When I said optional, I means if it is completely unnecessary to declare a `interceptor binding type` when I'm using **@Interceptors** on target class/method?

Comment: `Thus you need at least one interceptor binding for @Interceptors`  -  Value of @Interceptors is array of interceptor, right? Since I can using @Interceptors to apply array of interceptor to target class/method **directly**, I think there is no reason to declare a extra `interceptor binding type` in this case, that's my question.

Comment: You're absolutly right, "you don't need to apply an interceptor binding type since it's already included in @Interceptors(...)". Otherway you would use the same annotation twice....

Comment: Then why IntelliJ giving me a error `@Interceptor must specify at least one interceptor binding` when I do not declare any custom `interceptor binding type`, and only annotating @Interceptor on my interceptor?

Comment: Every interceptor has to have its owm binding type! If you decorate a class/method with **@Interceptors** and say you have specified the interceptor LoggerInterceptor.class with the type **@Logged** and decorate the same member with **@Logged**, than it's ok to leave out the annotation **@Logged** (Because you would have invoked it twice)... Read the java tutorial

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get it. I already binding my interceptor to target class/method with @Interceptors(arrayOfMyInceptor) **directly**, why declare a extra `interceptor binding type`? that's what confused me and why I asked this question, hope you understand.

Comment: Upvoted, and edit my question again. Many thanks for your patience!

Comment: See the updated answer. I recommend you to always search on the Java tutorial if you need to find any information on frameworks and technologies. Interceptors are actually pretty simple if you know where to read about them